# trying to make a ranking function base on mongodb, aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am making a ranking function by the user record made on differ date, and I was trying to use mongodb aggregate function. However I have no idea how to get a correct date that record made. let say I have the records below:

```
db.test.insert(
    [
        {
            'name':'a',
            'mark':100,
            'created' : new Date('2015-03-20')
        },

        {
            'name':'a',
            'mark':208,
            'created' : new Date('2015-03-21')
        },

        {
            'name':'a',
            'mark':200,
            'created' : new Date('2015-03-22')
        },
        {
            'name':'b',
            'mark':240,
            'created' : new Date('2015-03-25')
        },

        {
            'name':'b',
            'mark':20,
            'created' : new Date('2015-11-20')
        },

        {
            'name':'c',
            'mark':225,
            'created' : new Date('2015-11-21')
        },

        {
            'name':'c',
            'mark':305,
            'created' : new Date('2015-11-22')
        },
        {
            'name':'c',
            'mark':300,
            'created' : new Date('2015-11-22')
        }
    ]
);
```

and I had query like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        "_id":"$name",
        "mark" : {$max : "$mark"},
        "name": {$min : "$name"},
        "created" : {$max : "$created"}

    }},
    {$sort:{"mark":-1}}
])
```

and I got results:

```
{ "_id" : "c", "mark" : 305, "name" : "c", "created" : ISODate("2015-11-22T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : "b", "mark" : 240, "name" : "b", "created" : ISODate("2015-11-20T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : "a", "mark" : 208, "name" : "a", "created" : ISODate("2015-03-22T00:00:00Z") }
```

I expect user b best result is 240 and made on 2015-03-25, user a best result 208 and made on 2015-03-21.

I understand the problem is on

```
...
"created" : {$max : "$created"}
...
```

but I do not know what accumulator should I put, or I am having a wrong idea to do such function?
sorry I am very new on mongodb, wish I can have some insight here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see `$first` for this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$sort:{"name" : 1, "mark":-1}},
    {$group:{
        "_id":"$name",
        "mark" : {$max : "$mark"},
        createdDate: { $first: "$created" }

    }}
]);
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "_id" : "a",
    "mark" : 208,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-03-21T00:00:00.000Z")
}

{
    "_id" : "b",
    "mark" : 240,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-03-25T00:00:00.000Z")
}

{
    "_id" : "c",
    "mark" : 305,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-11-22T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Comment: thanks notionquest, but the user a getting a wrong date....do we have something like SQL join  on mongodb

Comment: Which user getting the wrong date? Can you provide that data?

Comment: sorry mate I found that is my mistake =)